Code generation for multi-platform, multi-language library
I need to design a code generator system that produces serialisation/deserialisation libraries for multiple languages running on multiple platforms.
Hard Constraints
I need this to capture a pre-existing binary serialisation format bit-for-bit. It cannot add frames, versions, etc. to the stream; therefore I think that e.g. Google Protobuf is not possible.
I can use open-source dependencies but the message definitions are closed-source.
I need to capture 20-some structure definitions that already exist but are currently non-portable.
I need to support C, C++, C# and Python targets.
I need to support structures that have the following C-like elements:

fixed-length arrays;
sub-structures;
C-like primitives for byte, int, char, float, double, enum

I need these library artefacts to be generated at compile time.
Whether in-library or out-of-library, I need to be able to serialise and deserialise these structures to pipe- or socket-like streams.
Soft constraints
Especially for the C/C++ targets, there should be very little overhead during the serialisation/deserialisation phase. In the ideal case, the output would simply be structure definitions with explicit pack/align attributes. I can assume that each structure is guaranteed to fit in memory.
It would be nice to use an off-the-shelf solution for this, but if no such solution exists then I am (reluctantly) open to hacking up my own.
The central protocol definitions should use some pre-existing, well-understood markup format like XML. Alternatively, if C# is the first-class platform, then I would be open to a system that annotates the C# structure versions and produces other language bindings from there.
It would be nice if the structure definition system had a versioning scheme (though this cannot influence the on-stream format). If this feature does not exist I will just rely on the repository's existing version control.
My solution should be data-centric and should not really have any business logic.
Pre-existing art
Best practices / Design patterns for code generation has some hints but is rather too vague.
Writing a API for a hardware device for mutliple platforms seems like it's more routine-focused than data-focused.
I cannot find any other questions that seem related enough.
Questions
What are the comparative design costs/risks to rolling this in-house versus using an off-the-shelf serialisation library; and do off-the-shelf frameworks for this kind of thing even exist?

You have a lot of information, but I'm not sure what your question is. Can you clarify?

Unless your data model happens to map directly to an existing serialization system, you're unlikely to find an existing code generator. For your sketch of the data model, arrays will be the tricky part. If these arrays all have statically known sizes, you're matching the C data model (without pointers) and can use existing tooling for creating C bindings. If arrays are encoded in any other way (e.g. prefixed with length), you will likely need a bespoke parser for your data format. I'd probably just write the codegen tool myself.

@GregBurghardt My questions are: what are the comparative design costs to rolling this in-house versus using an off-the-shelf serialisation library; and do off-the-shelf frameworks for this kind of thing even exist?

@amon Thanks. I edited the question to attempt to clarify. Arrays are always fixed-length and do not have length prefixes. Can you expand on "existing tooling"?

The .NET Roslyn compiler has support for code generation.  There are also NuGet pakages, like Json2Sharp that will create c# classes from a json.  Same for xml.

Numbers are important here. What does "20 some " mean, around 20 structures? How many attributes, substructures etc(roughly)? How often do these structures change? For around 20 structures, the most cost effective solution could be to implement the code manually, without a generator.

Unless your existing binary format matches a well-known described format, you are unlikely to find an existing library that can replicate your binary format.

Just recently I stumbled across the Apache Kafka wire protocol and the mechanisms by which the reference implementation (in Java) and other language bindings map a (more or less strict) specification into code. I only took a closer look at the Python implementation, but it might be worth looking at the others, too. In the end, you'll likely need to roll your own, but having good examples is almost as good as a finished library.

@DocBrown Starting at 20, with this number growing slowly (~5 per year, let's say); with moderate pace of change; assume one field changed per month. But the attributes can be many per struct, up to 100. You're right that manual code implementation is an option, but I think the risk there is human error.


capture a pre-existing binary serialisation format bit-for-bit.

Means: you must be very lucky to find a fully generic generator for this kind of serialization which will suit your needs. At least it needs to be highly customizable. Even if such a thing exists, you need to check if its configuration is really less complex than rolling out your own hand-coded program in a high-level language like C# or Python.*
*This answer mentions Kaitai, it might be worth a look.

I would be open to a system that annotates the C# structure versions and produces other language bindings

Well, that is what we did in the past for generating comparable code from a single source to different targets:

C# classes with annotated attributes/properties (but no methods) as input, compiled into an assembly

use reflection to iterate over the classes and their properties in the assembly, then generate whatever you want from it.


This saves you the hassle of writing a parser for the input data, and it will allow you to add any kind of annotations you need. It is a useful and effective approach when

the code for the generator as well as the input C# code is developed by the same team
annotated C# is descriptive enough for your requirements
the team is fine with using C# code as input

In fact, if I were in your shoes, I would give this approach a try and see where it gets you. If you end up with something between 1000 and 2000 lines of code for the generator (like us), there is no huge saving potential left, let alone the extra effort to find, evaluate, choose, learn and test some template based 3rd party system which partly supports what you need (and where you still will have to make custom adaptions to make the output match your requirements).
Let me finally add that all of your platforms may require some structure-independent low-level code for reading and writing binary data. If that is the case, and you think this part alone is complex enough to justify a common library, I would write this library in C, since C libraries can be consumed by all the other platforms you mentioned.

the code for the generator as well as the input C# code is developed by the same team - check. annotated C# is descriptive enough for your requirements - check. the team is fine with using C# code as input - There will be a certain amount of socialisation but I don't see any major issues.

Kaitai Struct does half of this: https://kaitai.io/ but doesn't emit writer code. Maybe you could use it to solve half of your problem then you only have to write the other half? Serialization is usually easier, too.
Python Construct does writers as well, but only in Python.
There's a good summary of some tools in this space.

Looks interesting. It seems Kaitai has added serialization for Python and Java, see https://doc.kaitai.io/serialization.html

@pjc50 Thanks very much; I'll read about Kaitai and Construct. You added a link and described it as a domain summary, but it's the link to the Construct docs; was that intentional?

The Kaitai approach itself seems very promising, though there may be some maintenance risk. Of course, if it works well, I could always fork it if I'm desperate.

@avigt: if I would need to maintain such a complex project by myself, or need to maintain my own little generator written in a programming language I am familar with, I think I know which alternative I would choose. I am pretty sure this will only pay off if you can use it out-of-the-box.

If you're starting from XML, the T4 support in Visual Studio may be useful if you want to roll your own generated code.  As far as I know, the logic parts of the T4 files have to be in a .NET language (I know VB and C# are both supported), but I don't think there's any requirement for the generated code to be in any particular language as it's ultimately a text template.  You would be able to have the logic for making a model of the source information in a common file, then have individual templates for the different destination languages which would consume that model.
I've found T4 to work very well for my purposes where I wanted to have a single source of truth used to generate boilerplate source code.

I like this solution and I'm pursuing it, despite T4 integration with modern .NET being a giant PITA.

@avigt You can hand-edit your project files to manage the build.  There are some issues with integration into solution views; it works well with C# but not with VB.  In C#, I see the generated .cs file as a child of the primary T4 file, while with VB I only see the T4 file.  The project will still build, though.

I don't think discussion of nuts and bolts would be on-topic here, but feel free to ping me if you open a question on Stack Overflow.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79269569/cannot-integrate-texttransformcore-exe-to-a-visual-studio-2022-net-9-project
